# how to use chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() in threads

Tags: c++, future

I'm using `chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` in my function to time how long a loop takes to get an estimated time of completion for x number of repeats. However, when called from main using `future`, it gives time that are just wrong. I've used Visual C++ and intel c compiler. How to solve this?

Comment: You will have to post actual code. Most likely your test code has some issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known [bug in VC](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/) and others, the header uses system clock which is not very high resolution. If you want really accurate timing either use boost or rdtsc.

Using boost you would use it as you would use the std::chrono, the example from the link:

```
 boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 while (t3==t4 ) {
    t4 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
 }
 boost::chrono::nanoseconds ns = t4 - t3;
```

A possible implementation of rdtsc

```
// On some processors in certain circumstances the value can be off
// on some old processors rdtsc doesn't exist.
// only valid for x86/x64.
// only valid when no thread switch happens between calls.
// will be wrong if cpu uses turbo mode or changes speed.
// ToDO check where. make fallback timer.
// will blow up if you run over the epoch, shouldn't happen as the epoch is ~136 years
// beware of cpu instruction reordering if timing very short functions.
static uint64_t tick() noexcept {
    unsigned lo, hi;
    asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
    return int64_t(hi) << 32 | lo;
}
```